# Getting Exception on published ASP.NET MVC4 app using Backload for file upload

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

While working in Visual Studio and testing my app, everything works just fine. I'm using Backload to upload files to server. However, when trying to upload files when publishing to local IIS server, I get following exception:

Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.

Complete stack trace is below:

```
[OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.]
   System.IntPtr.op_Explicit(IntPtr value) +37
   筦屎긑쾖㨚�䓝�.敕蛘᷏ꂫ�۟똿뽎() +2030
   .cctor() +115

[TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for '<Module>' threw an exception.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +159
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +256
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +127
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +11
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +92

[InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'Backload.Controllers.BackloadController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +256
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +81
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) +270
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +86
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +12550671
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288
```

IIS server has all the rights to write to upload folder. This error happens when trying to access backload on localhost/mySite/Backload/UploadHandler

Backload version used is 1.9.2.2 (and yes, I'm getting those chinese/japanese signs, no idea why)

EDIT: just tried importing examples from github and those get the exact same error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is related to issue #17 and will be fixed in the upcoming release 1.9.3.
Read here: https://github.com/blackcity/Backload/issues/17

Edit: 
Just saw, that there is a release candidate for the 1.9.3 release available on Nuget. You should check this release, and if the exception still exists notify the developers. They usually try to include bug fixes very fast.
http://www.nuget.org/packages/Backload/

Comment: current release candidate still has the bug, but it's different now, hopefully will be resolved for 1.9.3, thanks!